# This house has been furnished with a peculiar style. Is this use of 'peculiar' correct?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I was trying to give an example for a new word I was trying to learn, "peculiar". Is this correct?

> This house has been furnished with a peculiar style.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Paolo, and thanks for your question. Did you consult a [**dictionary**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peculiar)  to learn about _peculiar?_ Did you understand the definition? Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you to write good questions, and answers. (There is no need to include "Thank you" in your questions. We help here because we enjoy it!)

Comment: I had consulted the Cambridge and Oxford dictionaries but maybe my question was also about the usage of furnish. I actually wanted to make sure this sentence made sense. I've found the tour very helpful and clarifying.

Comment: It is correct; the use is applicable to the sentence.

Comment: A useful question would tell us exactly what you don't understand about the meanings of _furnish_ and _peculiar._ Your sentence as written would make sense, perhaps, but it is not the way we would write it in English. In your sentence, the verb _furnish_ should take the preposition _in_ (not _with_) when talking about the style of the furniture: **This house has been furnished _in_ a peculiar style.** We would use _with_ when talking about the furniture itself: _This house has been furnished with chairs._

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe I should have read the _furnish_ definition more carefully. In any case thanks for your answer and suggestions on how to ask my future questions

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peculiar) the word peculiar means:

- unusual and strange, sometimes in an unpleasant way. Belonging to, relating to, or found in only particular people or things.

The sentence will be correct and will have sense if we write it as:

> This house has been furnished in a peculiar style.

*'In style'* here means **"in what way?", "how?"** while *"with"* would mean **"something physical", "together with"**.